# Construct the Kernel (Fundamental Set of Solutions) of a Differential Operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I construct the kernel of the following differential operator in $[0,1]$:
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{d}{dx}(k(x)\frac{d}{dx})
$$
and $k(x) \in C([0,1])$, $k_{min} \leq k(x) \leq k_{max}, \forall x \in [0,1]$, for some $0<k_{min}<k_{max}$

In otherword, I am looking for the functions $\phi (x):[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $ such that $\mathcal{L} (\phi (x))=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote $D = d/dx$. Observe that the equation you want to solve is
$$D \cdot k(x) \cdot D \phi = k'(x) D \phi + k D^2 \phi = (k'(x) + k(x) \cdot D) (D \phi) = 0$$
Let us denote $\psi = D \phi$. Then we must solve the equation
$$k'(x) \psi + k(x) \cdot D \psi = 0 \implies D \psi = -\frac{k'(x)}{k(x)} \psi \implies \psi = \frac{C}{k(x)}$$
for some arbitrary constant $C$. This suggests a general solution
$$\phi(x) =  \int \frac{C}{k(x)} dx$$
Note that there will be another constant resulting from the indefinite integral above. (As expected, since your differential operator takes two derivatives.)

Another way to see it: if $D [k(x) D] \phi(x) = 0$, then $k(x) D \phi(x) = C$ for some constant $C$, which suggests that $D \phi = C / k(x)$, giving the same exact result.